# Expressing Connectives in terms of NOR

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need to show that $\phi\land\psi$, $\phi\lor\psi$ and $\neg\phi$ can be expressed by the connective NOR ($\downarrow$).

I've only gotten that $\neg\phi$ is equivalent to $\phi\downarrow\phi$ because I could easily check the truth table of $\neg(\phi\lor\phi)$.

But I'm struggling with defining the rest of the connectives. Does anyone have any $\textit{tips, hints or suggestions}$ about how to proceed?

Comment: If you can make $\lnot$ you can make $\lor$ ($a \lor b$ is equivalent to $\lnot ( a \downarrow  b)$)  and from there you can use De Morgan to get $\land$.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to not have the question answered for me, especially when the answer is so straightforward but thank you for the input.

Comment: Sorry, I will try harder to give less information in future :-).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the truth tables.  How does $\lnot$ change truth values?

Comment: It just flips them.